# How do Make 'Em Bleed, Open Wounds, and Witch-Hunt—buffs where enemies take additional damage—stack with similar effects?

Tags: warhammer-vermintide-2

In *Vermintide 2*, the following buffs:

| Buff | Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Make 'Em Bleed | Huntsman talent | Critical hits cause enemies to take 20% increased damage for 15 seconds. Does not stack with similar effects. |
| Open Wounds | Bounty Hunter talent | Critical hits cause enemies to take 20% increased damage for 15 seconds. Does not stack with similar effects. |
| Witch-Hunt | Witch Hunter Captain passive ability | Tagged enemies take an additional 20% damage. Does not stack with similar effects. The debuff can be applied by any player and affects all damage that enemy receives. Lasts for 15 seconds (the duration of the tag). |

…all have the effect of making affected enemies take 20% additional damage (from any source, including from teammates) for a short duration. They are also all described as "does not stack with similar effects." What exactly does "similar effects" mean in this context? I'm asking because there are also other buffs in the game that cause enemies to take additional damage temporarily, such as:

| Buff | Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Shrapnel | Trinket trait | Grenades cause hit enemies to take 20% increased damage for 10 seconds |
| Off-Balance | Melee weapon trait | Blocking an attack increases the amount of damage the attacker takes by 50% for 3 seconds |
| Bulwark | Level 15 talent on some careers | Enemies that you stagger take 10% more damage from melee attacks for 2 seconds |
| Exploit Weakness | Shade talent | Increase damage by 20% to poisoned or bleeding enemies |
| Ellinill's Withering | Chaos Wastes boon | Attacks against full health enemies deal 20% more damage |

<sup>Note: Please let me know if I missed a buff in the table above.</sup>

**How do the above talents and abilities stack with other effects in the game that cause enemies to take increased damage temporarily?**